# Invalid narrowing conversion from "float" to "int"

Tags: c++, vector, type-conversion, sfml, narrowing

I am using the SFML graphics library for C++. My compiler is Visual Studio 2017.

When I was making the function `scale` I encountered a problem. I had an error saying:

`Invalid narrowing conversion from "float" to "int"`

So, I put `roundf` in front of both items in the vector, but this didn't seem to help. Changing the `std::vector<int>` to `std::vector<float>` for the return value seems to work but I would like it as an integer. Any ideas? Here's my code:

```
std::vector<int> scale(sf::RenderWindow *Window, std::vector<int> offset)
{ // Scale objects
    float scale = 500;
    return { roundf(Window->getSize().x / scale * offset[0]), roundf(Window->getSize().y / scale * offset[1]) };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `lroundf()` to convert to a `long int` rather than `round()` which returns a float.  You may also need to cast the result of `lroundf()` to `int` (because that is usually narrower than `long`).

Like this:

```
return { int(lroundf(Window->getSize().x / scale * offset[0])), int(lroundf(Window->getSize().y / scale * offset[1])) };
```

Comment: thanks! I changed it to lroundf(), but didn't need the int(). Problem solved!